# I've got stuck with daterangepicker, Im triying to validate ranges dates, it works but Im inside a loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, loops, scope, daterangepicker

This is my situation; the daterangepicker is working, everything is working indeed, but there is a loop I cant find a way to avoid. Each time I choose a date range with invalid date Ive got the alert message but this never stop popping up. In fact, I found that if I hide all the code insideisInvalidDate and I just write a console.log, there is still a loop. Ive tried to take the validaterange function outside but as the variables are locals, the function doesnt work.
This is my .js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    idRoom = document.getElementById("room_name").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData/" + idRoom,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var today = new Date();
            var day =
                today.getFullYear() +
                "/" +
                today.getMonth() +
                +1 +
                "/" +
                today.getDate();
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                opens: "right",
                drops: "up",
                minDate: day,
                maxSpan: {
                    days: 15,
                },
                locale: {
                    format: "YYYY/MM/DD",
                },
                isInvalidDate: function (date) {
                    var len = response["data"].length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var Str = response["data"][
                            i
                        ].reservation_checkout.replace(/-/g, ","); //quitamos 1 dia al checkout para que ese dia este disponible
                        var newStr = new Date(Str);
                        newStr.setDate(newStr.getDate() - 1);
                        var newdate = new Date(newStr);
                        date[i] = newdate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
                    }
                    var dateRanges = []; //obtenemos los datos checking/checkout y los metemos en datepicker
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        dateRanges.push({
                            start: moment(
                                response["data"][i].reservation_checking
                            ),
                            end: moment(date[i]),
                        });
                    }
                    var dateRangesfix = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var startDatefix = moment(
                            response["data"][i].reservation_checking
                        ).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                        var endDatefix = moment(
                            response["data"][i].reservation_checkout
                        ).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                        dateRangesfix.push(startDatefix, endDatefix);
                    }

                    $('input[name="daterange"]').on(
                        "apply.daterangepicker",
                        function validateDateRange() {
                            var txtStartDate = $(
                                'input[name="daterange"]'
                            ).data("daterangepicker").startDate;
                            var txtEndDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data(
                                "daterangepicker"
                            ).endDate;
                            var startDate;
                            var endDate;
                            var tempDate;
                            if (txtStartDate == "") return false;
                            if (txtEndDate == "") return false;
                            startDate = new Date(txtStartDate);
                            endDate = new Date(txtEndDate);
                            for (i = 0; i < 2 * len; i++) {
                                var temp = dateRangesfix[i].split("-");
                                tempDate = new Date(
                                    temp[2],
                                    temp[1] - 1,
                                    temp[0]
                                );
                                if (
                                    startDate < tempDate &&
                                    endDate > tempDate
                                ) {
                                    alert("Invalid Date Range");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    return dateRanges.reduce(function (bool, range) {
                        return (
                            bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end)
                        );
                    }, false);

                },
            });
        },
    });
});


$("#button1").click(function (event) {
    startDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data("daterangepicker").startDate;
    var d = new Date(startDate),
        month = "" + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = "" + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    start_Date_fix = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    document.getElementById("start_Date").value = start_Date_fix;

    endDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data("daterangepicker").endDate;
    var d = new Date(endDate),
        month = "" + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = "" + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    end_Date_fix = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    document.getElementById("end_Date").value = end_Date_fix;

    //calcular numero de noches
    var date = $('input[name="daterange"]').val();
    var str = date.split("-");
    var startDate = str[0];
    var startDate_f = startDate.split("/");
    var startDate_fo = new Date(
        startDate_f[0],
        startDate_f[1] - 1,
        startDate_f[2]
    );
    var endDate = str[1];
    var endDate_f = endDate.split("/");
    var endDate_fo = new Date(endDate_f[0], endDate_f[1] - 1, endDate_f[2]);
    var Difference_In_Days = Math.round(
        (endDate_fo - startDate_fo) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    );

    var year = startDate_f[0];
    var month = startDate_f[1];
    var day = startDate_f[2].replace(/\s+/g, "");
    var guests = document.getElementById("guests").value;

    $.ajax({
        url:
            "calculatePrice/" +
            year +
            "/" +
            month +
            "/" +
            day +
            "/" +
            Difference_In_Days +
            "/" +
            idRoom +
            "/" +
            guests,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("total_amount").value = data;
        },
    });
});
```

I pasted a full copy but I suppose the problem should be in those lines. As youll see Im an newbie and I hope you understand my poor level of English. I've spent some time reading post but Im not really sure about this.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved, Ive just been able to take the function out like this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    idRoom = document.getElementById("room_name").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData/" + idRoom,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var today = new Date();
            var day =
                today.getFullYear() +
                "/" +
                today.getMonth() +
                +1 +
                "/" +
                today.getDate();
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                opens: "right",
                drops: "up",
                minDate: day,
                maxSpan: {
                    days: 15,
                },
                locale: {
                    format: "YYYY/MM/DD",
                },
                isInvalidDate: function (date) {
                    var len = response["data"].length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var Str = response["data"][
                            i
                        ].reservation_checkout.replace(/-/g, ","); //quitamos 1 dia al checkout para que ese dia este disponible
                        var newStr = new Date(Str);
                        newStr.setDate(newStr.getDate() - 1);
                        var newdate = new Date(newStr);
                        date[i] = newdate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
                    }
                    var dateRanges = []; //obtenemos los datos checking/checkout y los metemos en datepicker
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        dateRanges.push({
                            start: moment(
                                response["data"][i].reservation_checking
                            ),
                            end: moment(date[i]),
                        });
                    }

                    return dateRanges.reduce(function (bool, range) {
                        return (
                            bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end)
                        );
                    }, false);
                },
            });
            var len = response["data"].length;
            var dateRangesfix = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var startDatefix = moment(
                    response["data"][i].reservation_checking
                ).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                var endDatefix = moment(
                    response["data"][i].reservation_checkout
                ).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                dateRangesfix.push(startDatefix, endDatefix);
            }
            $('input[name="daterange"]').on(
                "apply.daterangepicker",
                function validateDateRange() {
                    var txtStartDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data(
                        "daterangepicker"
                    ).startDate;
                    var txtEndDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data(
                        "daterangepicker"
                    ).endDate;
                    var startDate;
                    var endDate;
                    var tempDate;
                    if (txtStartDate == "") return false;
                    if (txtEndDate == "") return false;
                    startDate = new Date(txtStartDate);
                    endDate = new Date(txtEndDate);
                    for (i = 0; i < 2 * len; i++) {
                        var temp = dateRangesfix[i].split("-");
                        tempDate = new Date(temp[2], temp[1] - 1, temp[0]);
                        if (startDate < tempDate && endDate > tempDate) {
                            alert("Invalid Date Range");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        },
    });
});

$("#button1").click(function (event) {
    startDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data("daterangepicker").startDate;
    var d = new Date(startDate),
        month = "" + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = "" + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    start_Date_fix = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    document.getElementById("start_Date").value = start_Date_fix;

    endDate = $('input[name="daterange"]').data("daterangepicker").endDate;
    var d = new Date(endDate),
        month = "" + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = "" + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    end_Date_fix = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    document.getElementById("end_Date").value = end_Date_fix;

    //calcular numero de noches
    var date = $('input[name="daterange"]').val();
    var str = date.split("-");
    var startDate = str[0];
    var startDate_f = startDate.split("/");
    var startDate_fo = new Date(
        startDate_f[0],
        startDate_f[1] - 1,
        startDate_f[2]
    );
    var endDate = str[1];
    var endDate_f = endDate.split("/");
    var endDate_fo = new Date(endDate_f[0], endDate_f[1] - 1, endDate_f[2]);
    var Difference_In_Days = Math.round(
        (endDate_fo - startDate_fo) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    );

    var year = startDate_f[0];
    var month = startDate_f[1];
    var day = startDate_f[2].replace(/\s+/g, "");
    var guests = document.getElementById("guests").value;

    $.ajax({
        url:
            "calculatePrice/" +
            year +
            "/" +
            month +
            "/" +
            day +
            "/" +
            Difference_In_Days +
            "/" +
            idRoom +
            "/" +
            guests,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("total_amount").value = data;
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend validating the date ranges server-side with Laravel's Validation
tools and Carbon if formatting is required. Instead of using the GET method on the price calculator route:

```
$.ajax({
    url:
        "calculatePrice/" +
        year +
        "/" +
        month +
        "/" +
        day +
        "/" +
        Difference_In_Days +
        "/" +
        idRoom +
        "/" +
        guests,
```

You would make a post request and use the Request $request typehint or Request facade to access incoming data and simply return the data from the calculator OR continue to use the GET method and pass the date input as a wildcard/route-parameter to.

If you require front-end validation, I would recommend using a Vue component and a package such as Vuelidate to simplify the process. In my experience, front-end validation is very time-consuming without using Vuelidate. This would be my recommendation, as there are plenty of date-picker Vue components available as well which can be configured to format on the front-end also.

(If by "alert" you meant an actual alert window and not a bootstrap component)
Sidenote: using Alerts to report validation errors is not practical and in my personal opinion, shouldn't be used. Instead, validate server-side and return error messages, check for error messages on the front end, and then display those messages near the input it's for.

It looks like you answered your own issue while I was typing this, so I'll leave it here anyway.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm gonna check this out. As I said I'm still a newbie so this advice are cool for me. Probably Ill ask you back some questions.